# I want to use an html file as my homepage on next.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

When someone visit my root directory "https://example.com/" i want to render a normal .html file. (index.html) How can i be able to do that with next.js?

I did a research and edit my config file like this,

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  rewrites: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: "/public/myfile.html",
        destination: "/pages/api/myfile.js",
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

/pages/api/myFile.js

```
import fs from "fs";
const filename = "/index.html";

export default async function api(req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
  res.write(await fs.readFileSync(filename, "utf-8"));
  res.end();
}

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

but this config file rendering my .html page just when i hit this url: https://example.com/index.html

Comment: There are two files/filenames being presented here: `index.html` and `myfile.html`. When someone visits the root (e.g., `https://example.com/`), you want the file `./public/myfile.html` to be served (and to appear as `index.html` in the browser's address bar) instead of what would've normally been generated from `./pages/index.js`. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply i solved it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  rewrites: async () => [
    {
      source: "/",
      destination: "/index.html",
    },
  ],
```

added this on my next.config.js file (in nextConfig object)

I have an index.html file on my /public directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Super easy way is pasting your html code with css and js in `public` folder, so you can route to `mywebsite.com/index.html` with no longer code :)

You can handle main url redirection from `next.config` file with adding this:
YOU HAVE TO DELETE MAIN INDEX.TSX OR PAGE.TSX FROM SRC OR APP FOLDER

```
rewrites: async () => [
    {
      source: "/",
      destination: "/index.html",
    },
  ],
```